# How should I keep the status bar and actionbar hidden through navigation in Nativescript?

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript

so currently I make an initial call to hide the status bar at the beginning of the app and also set the actionbar to hidden in the constructor of all my components, yet when I open the keyboard in android the status bar shows back up and doens't hide when the keyboard hides. How should I deal with this, especially given the fact that nativescript has no events for on keyboard open and close? I just need to maintain the status bar hidden after the keyboard closes (preferable always).

To be more specific I'm using Nativescript 3.0, Typescript, and Angular 2 in my project.

Answer (score 1):

You have the option to bootstrap the Angular application with no action bar bu [providing startPageAcrionBarHidden option](http://docs.nativescript.org/angular/core-concepts/angular-bootstrap.html#nativescript-application-options)

```
platformNativeScriptDynamic({startPageActionBarHidden: true});
```

For specific page you can use [actionBarHidden](http://docs.nativescript.org/angular/ui/action-bar.html#showing-or-hiding-the-actionbar) property on page

e.g.

```
import { Page } from "ui/page";

constructor(private page: Page) {
    this.page.actionBarHidden = true;
}
```

Comment: it's only for ActionBar, not for status-bar, right?

Comment: Yep the above approach is just for hiding the ActionBar

Comment: You can try this plugin for showing/hiding the status bar https://github.com/PeterStaev/NativeScript-Status-Bar or directly use the native code for Android https://github.com/PeterStaev/NativeScript-Status-Bar/blob/master/status-bar.android.ts#L25 and for iOS https://github.com/PeterStaev/NativeScript-Status-Bar/blob/master/status-bar.ios.ts#L29