# What is the right way to hide the status bar in nativescript using angular template?

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript

How can I hide the status bar for a specific activity?

I found this similar question, but none of the answers worked for me.

[Ref # 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44961846/how-should-i-keep-the-status-bar-and-actionbar-hidden-through-navigation-in-nati)

[Ref # 2](https://github.com/PeterStaev/NativeScript-Status-Bar/blob/master/status-bar.android.ts#L25)

[Ref # 3](https://github.com/PeterStaev/NativeScript-Status-Bar)

[Ref # 4](https://bradmartin.net/2016/03/10/fullscreen-and-navigation-bar-color-in-a-nativescript-android-app/)

The app just crashed every time and shows me the error cannot read property `getWindow` while running my app on genymotion andriod VM. Below is the brief error screen shot

[image]

**Below is my home.component.ts code**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import {Page} from "ui/page";
import * as app from "tns-core-modules/application";

@Component({
    selector: "Home",
    moduleId: module.id,
    templateUrl: "./home.component.html",
    styleUrls: ["./home.component.scss"]
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor(page: Page) {
        page.actionBarHidden = true;
        this.statusBar('hide');
    }

    ngOnInit(): void {

        // Init your component properties here.
    }

    statusBar(action: string){
        var activity = app.android.startActivity;
        //activity.runOnUiThread(function(){
        var win = activity.getWindow();
        if(action === 'hide'){
            win.addFlags(app.android.nativeApp.view.WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        } else if(action === 'show'){
            win.clearFlags(app.android.nativeApp.view.WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        }
    }
}
```

Please help me on this. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use [nativescript-status-bar](https://github.com/PeterStaev/NativeScript-Status-Bar) plugin.

```
import * as statusBar from 'nativescript-status-bar'

// Show
statusBar.show();

// Hide
statusBar.hide();
```

Comment: in my above ref I mentioned this plugin link. I try this one in my home component and use show and hide method but still its not hiding the status bar. Second thing is that may be there is something I need to add in my module.ts which I don't know. That's why it is not working.

Comment: It works perfectly fine on my end. If you have issues, please share a Playground Sample.

Comment: Here is my Playground https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=tz7RPF but it shows me some device errors in my playground console ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: com.tns.NativeScriptException: Failed to find module: "nativescript-status-bar", relative to: app/tns_modules/

Comment: did you importing anything else in your module.ts file or whatever in component?

Comment: While using the plugin within Playground, you must follow relative path to import plugin. Secondly you are accessing the methods too early, either wait for loaded event of your root view or created event of activity.

Comment: Please share me your working playground link so I can easily find the problem in my code.

Comment: Try this - https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=tz7RPF&v=2

Comment: You may put it on ngAfterViewInit of app component.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for solution to view app full screen and hide status bar then use:

```
var activity = app.android.foregroundActivity || app.android.startActivity;
var window = activity.getWindow();
window.clearFlags(android.view.WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(isAndroid){
    Application.android.startActivity.getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(android.view.View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN)
}
```

The code above would let you hide the statusbar on an android device, the snippet about works fine on Nativescript7 and above.

You can also implement this within onNgInit method, so as to hide the statusbar as you navigate to the page or component.

Comment: please, add some details, explain why you posted this code